# Flutter: Use same app in web ,android and ios

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

How do I build the flutter app that can be built for web and the same application be used on our existing android/ios apps.

We already do have existing apps, we are looking to move towards flutter. Can we build a piece of our app in flutter, plug it into existing apps and use the same app in web too?

Abhi

Answer (score 2):

To enable Flutter Web

```
flutter config --enable-web
```

then go into an existing Flutter project and run

```
flutter create .
```

and your project will be configured for web.

To disable Web:

```
flutter config --no-enable-web
```

More info [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web).

Answer (score 1):

You may use conditional import:

```dart
import 'some_package_stub.dart'
    if (dart.library.io) 'some_package_io.dart'
    if (dart.library.html) 'some_package_web.dart';
```

`some_package_stub.dart` file is required to avoid error while developing and compiling. It must contains some `stub` functionality which depends on running platform.

For example if you use function `getPlatformDependedData` from package `some_package` which returns different data under Web or Android, than you should declare the prototype of those function ins `some_package_stub.dart`:

```dart
String getPlatformDependedData() {
  throw UnimplementedError('This error will not raised!');
}
```

Then in the code you can use `isWeb` constant to check if code is web related:

```dart
if (isWeb) {
  // some web related statements
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web) You need to run these commands in your terminal:

1. `flutter channel stable`
2. `flutter upgrade`
3. `flutter config --enable-web`
4. Restart your project
5. `flutter create .`
6. Done

Answer (score -1):

With regards to the question: can I build a flutter app that can be run in browsers, flutter for the web has been launched recently. You can find more info here:[flutter web](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web)